# C++ Boost Object Serialization - Periodic Saving to Protect Data

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have a program that uses boost serialization that loads on program start up and saves on shutdown.

Every once in a while, the program will crash due to this or that and I expect that to be fairly normal. The problem is that when the program crashes, often the objects are not saved at all. Other times, some will be missing or the data will be corrupted. This could be disastrous if a user loses months and months of data. In a perfect world, every one would backup their data and they could just roll back the data file.

My first solution is to periodically save the objects to a different temporary data file during run time. That way if the program crashes they can revert to the temporary data file with minimal data loss. My concern is the effect on performance. As far as I understand (correct me if I am wrong), once you save an object, it can't be used anymore? If that is the case, then the periodic save routine would involve saving and deleting my pointers, then loading them up again.

My second solution is to simply make a copy of the data file during program start up. The user's loss of data would be limited to that session. However, this may not be sufficient as some users may run the program for days and days.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_once you save an object, it can't be used anymore_" Where did you come across this?

Comment: I can't remember exactly. I remember reading it somewhere in the Boost documentation when I first starting using the serialization library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save an object graph with boost serialization, that object graph is still available and can be saved again without necessarily reading anything from disk.

If you want to go high-tech and introduce a lot more complexity, you can use Boost Interprocess library with a `managed_shared_memory` segment. This enables you to actually transparently work directly on a disk file (actually, on memory pages backed by file blocks). This introduces another issue, actually: how to *prevent* changes from frequently hitting the disk.

*Gratuitous advice:*

I think the best of all worlds would be if your object graph is (e.g.) a [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) where all nodes are shared immutables. Now serialization is "free" (with Boost), you can easily handle multiple versions of the program state (often a "document" or "database", logically) and efficiently save/load them with Boost Serialization. This pattern facilitates undo/redo, concurrent operations, transactional commit **¹** etc.

---

**¹** (! not without extra work, but in principle)